# Loop to find an empty cell in a column, then copy the cell above the empty cell into the empty cell

Tags: vba

I have a SAP report in Excel with over 10,000 rows. There are 2 columns - A & B. A is value in $ and B is ref for the value. The SAP report shows subtotals by reference type but the subtotal ref cell B is always empty. I need to copy the cell above the empty cell into the empty cell (into the same row as the subtotal). e.g. A1:A5 has values 3,2,3,1,1 so the subtotal is 10 and it's in A6. the cell in B6 is empty. The ref type in B5 is 12kg Bag. I need to copy this ref into Cell B6. the reason why i do this is because i filter the report by subtotal to copy to another file. At the moment I'm doing this manually and it takes ages. I'm guessing it's a loop code until the last row as the rows vary each time i run the report. Thank you!

Comment: Are you familiar with Visual Basic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? This sub loops over all rows and checks if the cell in column B is empty but the cell in column A contains a value. If so, it copies the cell in column B from the previous row into the current row.

```
 Sub fillEmptyCells()
 'copies the above cell for each empty cell in B where the cell in A is not empty
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    lastRow = ws.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row   'This gives the last Row with a nonempty cell in column A
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, 2)) And Not IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, 1)) Then
            ws.Cells(i - 1, 2).Copy ws.Cells(i, 2)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Edit: here is the same sub with a `with` environment

```
 Sub fillEmptycells()
 'copies the above cell for each empty cell in B where the cell in A is not empty
     Dim i As Integer
     Dim lastRow As Integer

     With ActiveSheet
         lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row   'This gives the last Row with a nonempty cell in column B
         For i = 1 To lastRow
             If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 2)) And Not IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 1)) Then
                 .Cells(i - 1, 2).Copy .Cells(i, 2)
             End If
         Next i
     End With
 End Sub
```

Comment: WOW!!!!  amazing code - works 100%.  work of a genius. You've just saved me 30 mins of extra work everyday.. Thank you sooooo much!!